# Filter for folders in Layer Panel

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There are way filter for folders in Layer Panel? I know I can filter layers and folders for name, attribute and other. But maybe Photoshop have hidden symbols in name of folders?
Example video, where I added unique symbol «-» in start of folder name
https://up.kibakoapp.com/iQNjIdsvaT

Answer (score 0):

There is a search by name if you choose Name attribute from Filter menu:[image]

Comment: I know about this filter, and I demostrate his work in example video. But I want sort only folders without layers